# ObservableCollection.Add() calls a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a strange dilemma that is making no sense. When I call `properties.Add` after a button click, the debugger shows a `NullReferenceException`.

The error is shown in the following constructor for MainWindow():

```
class GlobalProperties
{
    public ObservableCollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Problem> Issues { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Tennant> Tennants { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //...
    GlobalProperties globalProperties = new GlobalProperties();

    public MainWindow(User curUser)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Property> properties = globalProperties.Properties;
        properties.Add(new Property("58 Huet St", "Nundah", "4012", 4000.00, new LinkedList<Tennant>(), 5, 4, 2, 0, "Beautiful house. In Nundah. It's pretty cool. And you should live there. This is an optional piece of text.", new LinkedList<Photo>(), "Home", 48.23, 86.74, "Humid", new LinkedList<Problem>(), "Townhouse", 2004, 1800)); // This line has the problem
        globalProperties.Properties = properties;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

Why am I getting this `NullReferenceException`? It was working perfectly before I set up some Binding things on the MainWindow, after which it started giving me this.

**Edit:** Found the StackTrace:

```
at VentureVisions.view.MainWindow..ctor(User curUser) in c:\Source\Stuff\CS IA\VentureVisions\VentureVisions\view\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 36
at VentureVisions.view.Login.OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e) in c:\Source\Stuff\CS IA\VentureVisions\VentureVisions\view\Login.xaml.cs:line 42
at System.Windows.Window.WmClose()
at System.Windows.Window.WindowFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.PublicHooksFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
```

Comment: a stack trace might be useful

Comment: Why this strange stack check and not simply set a flag (e.g. a bool field)?

Comment: also, what bindings did you add to the `MainWindow` that prompted the exception to start occurring?

Comment: Is it happening at calling this.Close(); or in the method itself?

Comment: It's happening at this.Close() and I added a binding to a property within `MainWindow` called properties. I'm writing a real estate management program just for context. I bound it to the ItemsSource of an ItemsControl.

Comment: @Clemens... Could you explain what you mean by a flag? I'll look it up, but I'd like a small explanation of what you mean

Comment: Your code sample as supplied works as expected (with some minor edits around the Controller because I don't have it). There's something else in your application that is causing the problem. You mentioned that you added some bindings on the MainWindow and the issue started happening, so the problem is likely in the MainWindow. It just looks like its coming from this.Close() because that's where OnClosing is called (which in turn creates and shows the MainWindow instance).

Comment: In That case (and now I changed it to comment out //this.close() and just open MainWindow, it's giving me a NullreferenceException at this point, where I try to add a property to properties. `            properties.Add(new Property(...));` More specifically, it's putting it when I'm trying to put a `new LinkedList<Problem>` in the constructor.

Comment: Well you try commenting ` base.OnClosing(e);` or set `e.Cancel = true;` in `if (wasCodeClosed)` block.

Comment: @EthanBrouwer What I mean is a private bool member variable (call it e.g. `wasCodeClosed`) that you set to true before calling Close, and check in OnClosing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the stack trace you posted, `NullReferenceException` is thrown in the constructor of `MainWindow`, in line 36 of `MainWindow.xaml.cs` to be exact.

Try checking that and if you're still stuck, post the code of that constructor as well, marking the problematic source code line.

EDIT:

Try adding the following constructor to `GlobalProperties` and check if that fixes the problem:

```
public GlobalProperties()
{
    Properties = new ObservableCollection<Property>();
    Photos = new ObservableCollection<Photo>();
    Issues = new ObservableCollection<Problem> ();
    Tennants = new ObservableCollection<Tennant>();
}
```

Comment: I found that out after looking at it, and I thought it may be throwing an error because I was trying to add elements to a property so I changed it to set a variable to that property, then change that variable, then set the property to that variable again but that didn't work. I'll post the code in a moment.

Comment: @EthanBrouwer Based on the code you posted, `globalProperties.Properties` doesn't seem initialized. I expanded my answer with a suggested fix.

Comment: I did that just before I saw your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var window = new MainWindow();
Application.Current.MainWindow = window;
window.Show();
this.Close();
```

Comment: That fixed the exception at this.close() but now the same exception is coming up somewhere else. I'll post exactly where.